# Filtering non-primitive types with hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, soft-delete

In my database I do not delete objects. Instead a soft delete is done. Means a delted flag is set to true. This should be filtered by hibernate using the @Filter annotation. 
This works but I have the problem that fields are not filtered.

For example I have a child class and a parent class which contains a child. If the child gets deleted and the parent gets loaded the parent object contains the child object (although the deleted flag is set correctly). But I want the child object to be filtered like it works with collections.
Is there any way to do that?

I tried treating the field like a collecting but this didn't work for me.

```
@Entity
@FilterDef(name = deletedFilter, parameters = @ParamDef(name = deletedParam, type = "boolean"))
@Filter(name = deletedFilter, condition = ":deletedParam = deleted")
public class Child {}


@Entity
public class Parent {
    @OneToOne
    @Filter(name = deletedFilter, condition = ":deletedParam = deleted")
    private Child child = new Child();
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't you have the `@OneToMany` on a collection?

Comment: Yes you're right. I will change it :-) But since in my code it is correct this doesn't change the behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hibernate filters are not working on `@OneToOne` relations.

https://hibernate.onjira.com/browse/HHH-4026

The explanation is on the comments to the issue: filters would change the cardinality of the relation.

Comment: OK thank you for the answer. Then i have to find another solution.

Comment: Okay, anything has changed with the latest version of JPA? Please provide a working link. Link above not working.

Answer (score 0):

If the boolean flag doesn't work you can use **Integer** value instead. And can check accordingly.